# Create a Method with Dynamic Action parameter

Tags: c#

Hi is there a way to create a method which accepts any kind of method? i mean any kind of parameter it has or how many parameter it has

```
void SampleMethod(Action<dynamic> Action)
{
}
```

I'm currently doing it like it but i think i doing it wrong is there a way to do that? whether it has a parameter or many or without parameter.

Am i doing wrong or i just miss something?

I have tried this code

```
void SampleMethod(Action Action)
{
}
```

but it seems that it only accepts the method without a parameter
Am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do with the method? Without knowing how many parameters it gets and which type they are, how are you going to call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Reflection,

```
    SampleMethod(this.GetType().GetMethod("WriteHello"), "Hello");

    public void WriteHello(string param)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(param);
    }

    public void SampleMethod(MethodInfo mi, params object[] arguments)
    {
        mi.Invoke(this,arguments);           
    }
```

Comment: BTW we can extend this approach with more reflection. But I think if we will set the method params. We should know them first.Thus it  has no sense finding out the kind params. I just answered according to my understanding of question.

Answer (score 3):

I think `Delegate` is what you're looking for.

```
static void A1() {
  Console.Out.WriteLine("A1");
}

static void A2(int foo) {
  Console.Out.WriteLine("A2");
}

static void SampleMethod(Delegate dlgt) {
}
```

Usage:

```
SampleMethod(new Action(A1));
SampleMethod(new Action<int>(A2));
```

You can invoke the method via `DynamicInvoke`(), however you'll have to provide exact list of arguments.

```
static void SampleMethod(Delegate dlgt) {
  // ok for A1, will throw an exception for A2
  dlgt.DynamicInvoke(null);
}
```